# How to iterate values from a dataframe and pass the values to a send email function in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mime, smtplib

I Have a dataframe `(df)` like below

```
Subject                       To_Address       CC_Address                       Backup_Address
Invoice 2345 is invalid       xyz@gmail.com     koke@gmail,ali@gmail.com         a@gmail.com
Invoice 3456 is invalid       abc@gmail.com     jack@gmail.com,ali.gmail.com     b@gmail.com
Invoice 3673 is invalid       bcd@gmail.com     peach@gmail.com,ali.gmail.com    e@gmail.com
Invoice 8978 is invalid                         rock@gmail.com,ali.gmail.com     c@gmail.com
Invoice 8078 is invalid                         rock@gmail.com,ali.gmail.com     d@gmail.com
Invoice 3173 is invalid       mnb@gmail.com     mone@gmail.com,ali.gmail.com     f@gmail.com
```

I need to send unique email for each row of the dataframe with

```
Email Subject = df[Subject] ,Email To Address =df[To_Address], Email_CC_Address = df[CC_Address]
```

Also Expection condition ned to be added, `Email To Address` is null or NaN then `Email To Address =df[Backup_Address]` should be passed

How can this be done in python.

**My current code which runs with static values**

```
def create_message(send_from, send_to,cc_to,subject, plain_text_body):
    message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    message['From'] = send_from
    message['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
    message['Cc'] = cc_to
    message['Subject'] = subject
    message.attach(MIMEText(plain_text_body, 'plain'))
    return message


subject = "Invoice is invalid"
sender_address = "sender@gmail.com.com"
to = "to@gmail.com"
cc_to = "cc@gmail.com"
mail_content="This is a test message"

message = create_message(sender_address,[to],cc_to,subject,mail_content)

send_message(message)
```

Comment: If it's a CSV/TSV file, maybe using plain CSV module is a better option than using Pandas here.

Comment: @Arunmozhi, I write the pandas dataframe to CSV file, I not sure how to iterate and pass the values and send indivual emails.

Comment: Don't create a multipart container if the message only actually has one body part. Like its name suggests, multipart is for when you have more than one body part, like a main message and an attachment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looping through the rows and multiple columns in parallel in the dataframe with `zip`:

```
def create_message(send_from, send_to, cc_to,subject, plain_text_body):
    sender_address = "sender@gmail.com.com"
    mail_content="This is a test message"
    for a, b, c, d in zip(df['Subject'], df['To_Address'], df['CC_Address'], df['Backup_Address']):
        if b == '':
            send_to = d
        else:
            send_to = b
        subject = a
        cc_to = c
        message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        message['From'] = send_from
        message['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
        message['Cc'] = cc_to
        message['Subject'] = subject
        message.attach(MIMEText(plain_text_body, 'plain'))
        return message


message = create_message(sender_address,[to],cc_to,subject,mail_content)

send_message(message)
```

Comment: this `else: to = d`  should `else:send_to = d`, I am correct

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over a Pandas DataFrame, you can use [`DataFrame.iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html).

But Iteration over a df isn't something that's recommended as it's considered as an "Anti-Pattern"..

Recommended Reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas/55557758)